# Can this equation be treated as a linear first order ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$yy'+f(x)y^2=yg(x)$$

Obviously it’s not linear, but couldn’t you divide by y and have a linear equation? If you solved that equation, what are the implications of dividing by y since y could be 0?

Comment: Divide by $y$ both side, and $y=0$ can be a singular solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the equation becomes
$$y'+f(x)y=g(x), y \ne 0 \implies \frac{d}{dx} \left(e^{\int f(x)  dx} y \right) = g(x) e^{\int f(x) dx}$$
$$\implies y(x)=e^{-\int f(x) dx} \int e^{\int f(x) dx} g(x) dx +C e^{-\int f(x) dx}$$

Answer (score 0):

The principal implication is that you lose $ y = 0 $ as a solution of your ODE, since you would be supossing that $ y \neq 0$, also this could cause trouble if you have an IVP or your solution has roots on the needed domain.

Comment: Alright that makes a lot of sense. Thanks!